# Can I access a local directory in google colab?

Tags: python, file-io, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am trying to do something similar to:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Me\Directory\Data_Files')
```

So I can then see all of my data files.  I know about the file upload command, but my experience has been that it takes too long to upload to a virtual machine especially for kaggle competition sized files.

Comment: If `files.upload()` - the actual way of doing it - is too slow for your task, try to follow two other methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264330/6818619).